# DaVinci Resolve Symbol Lookup Error on Fedora 39 within VanillaOS Orchid's Apx Container

Tags: fedora, libraries, container

I'm encountering a challenging issue trying to run DaVinci Resolve within an Apx application container on Fedora 39, which is running under VanillaOS Orchid. Despite my efforts to troubleshoot, including extensive research and experimentation, I'm at a standstill. I'm seeking insights or solutions from this forum, since I'm intermediate at Linux, and haven't found solutions anywhere else. :/

Environment:
-Host OS: VanillaOS Orchid
-Container: ApxContainer
-OS: Fedora 39
-Application: DaVinci Resolve
-Issue: Upon launching DaVinci Resolve, I encounter the following symbol lookup error related to libpango-1.0.so.0 and libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0:

```
./resolve: symbol lookup error: /lib64/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0: undefined symbol: g_task_set_static_name
```

Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

-Verified dependencies with ldd and addressed missing ones.
-Ran ldconfig and attempted to install libglib2.0-0, which was not found.
-Checked installed glib versions with dnf list installed | grep glib.Reinstalled pango and gdk-pixbuf2 using dnf reinstall.
-Checked symbol existence with nm -D /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0 | grep g_string_free_and_steal.
-Experimented with LD_PRELOAD to explicitly load libglib-2.0.so.0 and libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0.
-Ensured LD_LIBRARY_PATH was not interfering.Despite these efforts, the issue persists.
-Many, MANY other things;
I have looked up the problem Google, Reddit, and relevant forums without finding a solution that resolves the specific errors I'm facing.

Questions:

Has anyone successfully run DaVinci Resolve under similar conditions, and if so, how did you overcome such symbol lookup errors?

Are there known compatibility issues with DaVinci Resolve, Fedora 39, and the libraries in question that I might have missed?

Could this issue be related to running within an Apx container, and are there specific considerations or configurations for library paths or compatibility?

Any recommendations on further troubleshooting steps or alternative approaches to get DaVinci Resolve running smoothly in this environment?

Thank you for any insights or advice you can provide. I'm eager to find a solution, thanksies in advanced :3

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same error on Fedora 39. [This GitHub guide](https://github.com/H3rz3n/Davinci-Resolve-Fedora-39-Fix) fixed it for me. DaVinci Resolve 39 ships with some outdated libraries that seem to conflict with installed system libraries, and copying the ones mentioned in the guide to a `disabled-libraries` subfolder did the trick.